# QNAP NAS Won't Boot on 1/1/2021

Tags: qnap

Our 4xHDD QNAP stopped responding, booting, no beep exactly on 1/1/2021.

Could there be something with the timing, or could the hardware really have failed?

This is the hardware we have.

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00S0XU2HK/ref=ppx_od_dt_b_asin_title_s02?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00S0XU2HK)

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/kq9io1/some_supermicro_x9_motherboards_soft_lock_when/

Can you get into the BIOS and change the date?

Comment: The motherboard seemed to have failed.  Exactly around the stroke of midnight.  Very strange but the fans were turning off, and it overheated.  See my answer for details.  BTW I wasn't able to get into the Bios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ordered a replacement, insert the Hard Drives in the new system, and when it booted.  I was able to see the log alerts.  It shows the fan1 and fan2 were turning on and off, causing it to start overheating.  It was pretty slick that I was able to see the history of what was happening before it died.